# AWS CloudFormation package does not upload local Lambda files to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to upload local artifacts that are referenced in CF template to an S3 bucket using `aws cloudformation package` command and then deploy the packaged one to S3. Then, when I run the command:

```bash
aws cloudformation package --template-file template-file.yaml --s3-bucket my-app-cf-s3-bucket
```

It creates the packaged YAML file but does not upload anything to my S3 bucket.

Here is my CloudFormation

```yaml
Resources:
  MyUserPoolPreSignupLambda:
    type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: MyUserPoolPreSignup
      Code: lambda-pre-signup.js
      Runtime: nodejs-16
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you provided IAM user credentials for the AWS CLI (credentials file / Env variables)
2. If the template has no change, CLI won't upload files for multiple calls. To upload forcefully even if there is no change in your template, use '--force upload'

   --force-upload (boolean) Indicates whether to override existing files in the S3 bucket. Specify this flag to upload artifacts even if they match existing artifacts in the S3 bucket.

Comment: I have the credentials as I can deploy cloudformations. I also tried it with `--force-upload` but no luck. It does not even show error or warning regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in my cloudformation template. The `type` property must be capitalized:

`type: AWS::Lambda::Function` instead of `Type: AWS::Lambda::Function`